# Preview Excel, Word, PDF in Web browser

Tags: excel, pdf, ms-word, preview

Except for Google docs is there any technology that will allow me to provide a preview for Excel, Word, PDF from within the browser without having to download & installing anything new (of course I excpect they have at least those porgrams running on their computer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the files as HTML in Word/Excel. I am pretty sure Acrobat lets you do this with PDF too. You could also automate this process using VBA with Office docs.